# In Django how can I preserve the database state after a test function?

Tags: django, django-testing

Suppose I have 3 test functions in my testcase Class. test1 does A before all the asserts statements and test2 does AB and test3 does ABC.

A, B, C all mean some database creations. Based on the mechanism of Django TestCase, for each test function it will create a new database. However, in my case test3 depends on the data state of test2 and test2 depends on the state of test1.

I have several questions:

1. Is there an elegant way to deal with this kind of test problem? (I know fixtures can be useful. But I want to maintain the data dynamically created in the previous test functions)
2. I strongly believe unittests should be independent. How do you deal with the inter-relation tests in the layer of database in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to use the previous test cases in order to write your next test case. In such a situation you can define the basic functionality in the `setUp()` function. Then in the test cases accordingly use the `setUp`. The setUp function is called at the start of each test case.

Comment: Thanks! I got what I should do next.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly when there are dependent unit test functions, you need to check the code that you are testing first. The code needs to be broken down into a units that are unit testable.

But there could be some exceptions, in those cases grouping the test functions together into one would make the most sense. Because when you test a function, you are testing the functionality of the whole function and not parts of it.