# How to preserve database table between tests in django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing

How to preserve the database entries between tests in Django testing?

```
python3 manage.py test tests --keepdb
```

`--keepdb` preserves the database but not the table.
The tables get flushed between the tests.

Here is pseudo-code

```
from django.test import TestCase

class test_1(TestCase):
    def function_1(self):
        # Creates an entry in the database with file_path
         someModel.objects.create(file_path=file_path)

class test_2(TestCase):
    def function_2(self):
        # needs the file_path to execute this function
         someModel.objects.get(file_path=file_path)
```

`function_2` returns an error where file_path is not found since someModel table in the database has been flushed between the tests

How can I preserve the database table between the tests so they can find the file path?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613117/how-to-preserve-django-test-database-after-running-test-cases) (talks about preserving the actual database and not the table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827392/in-django-how-can-i-preserve-the-database-state-after-a-test-function) (creating a chain setUp does not work if I have 100´s tests that are chained) do not cover it.

Comment: Why are those even 2 different tests since you need that data? There's no order guarantee between tests anyway, you might end up running `test_2` first and `test_1` second totally breaking it even if you use `SimpleTestCase` or `unittest.TestCase` to skip the transaction / rollbacks. Also unit tests as the name suggests is about testing individual units of code, not a sequence of actions (You could kind of simulate that by testing going from one state to another while setting up the initial state for each test)

Comment: Even if I would to add `def function_2(self):` within the same class, it would still clear the data and get an error. How can we do a sequence of actions than as tests?

Comment: Don't the questions you linked already answer those? Just set up your data in functions like [setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) or similar.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, the challenge with `setUpTestData` is that it has to "re-run" to create the data needed instead of actually taking it from previous test cases. In my case, this is time-consuming since each function takes several minutes (machine learning model).
So by the time the test has reached the 10th test case, it would have accumulated to hours. Therefore, I wanted to share the data table between the tests instead of recreating for each individual unit test. I hope this cleared it out.

Comment: I am going through PyTest now, and seems like they have `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")`, I will test it and see if it actually fits the purpose mentioned above.

Comment: What are you doing training your ML models in the tests? Perhaps you should look into mocking things...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am not training, I am testing the model output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249405/discussion-between-polarbear10-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).